# How to reiterate echo output in horizontal format?

Tags: linux

I want this output:
a b c d e

When I try:

```
for letter in {a..e}; do
  echo $letter 
done
```

I get this output:

```
a
b
c
d
e
```

I tried this:

```
for letter in {a..e}; do
  echo -e "\t$letter" 
done
```

Output:

```
      a
      b
      c
      d
      e
```

It only transfers it to whole line to next tab!

Answer (score 4):

Your Echo appends a newline by default after each run. You can

- Supply the whole brace expansion as an argument, so that Echo runs a single time. It already separates its arguments by spaces.

  ```
  echo {a..e}
  ```
- Use `-n` so as to not have a newline after each run, manually appending a space after the variable expansion.

  ```
  for letter in {a..e}; do
      echo -n "$letter " 
  done
  ```
- Use Printf ([Why is Printf better than Echo?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/65803)).

  ```
  printf "%s " {a..e}
  ```

Comment: @user432797 You are welcome. Yes, printf should not be in a loop if you don't want the output to be repeated 5 times. Only the 2nd alternative needs to be in a loop.

Comment: @user432797 code highlighting in comments works with a single ` but it cannot have a space between the code and the ` symbol ... with spaces ` code `  and without spaces `code`

Comment: @Quasímodo...thank you! I was trying to loop the command, in case of printf, when I loop it, it repeated the a to e 5 times : `for letter in {a..e}; do printf "%s " {a..e} done` output `a b c d e a b c d e a b c d e a b c d e a b c d e`

Comment: @jsotola thank you!, I just updated the comment.